# Tag synonyms not working as expected?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

After seeing that bicycles had 38 questions tagged as [chain] and 2 as [chains], I suggested a tag synonym for the two and then approved it. Now, searching on the tag [chain](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chain) returns one question, even though looking it up in the list of tags still shows there are 38 questions.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I not be approving my own tag synonym suggestions? Does it simply take some time for the system to catch up?

(Perhaps this relates to the current network upgrades?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you flipped to the unanswered tab by accident?

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chain?sort=unanswered&pagesize=15